# Asynchronous calls though external SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

How to run asynchronous calls though external `C# ADO.Net`?.
How to execute queries asynchronously,BeginExecuteQuery??.

Do you have an example to run...

I have a stored procedure that is executing several inserting statements, the values are selected from a table,as They are independent, `TABLE_A, TABLE_B`, I would like to execute...

```
EXEC ('SELECT * FROM .. INTO TABLE_A')

and 

EXEC ('SELECT * FROM .. INTO TABLE_B')
```

Comment: one option is to use a BackgroundWorker. Please explain your context...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are wanting to do correctly, then yes, you can do asynchronous calls for the 3 commands, ExecuteReader,ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteXmlReader. The asynch versions have a Begin/End piece, e.g. BeginExecuteReader, EndExecuteReader and would work for what you are after. You have a few options in terms of how to handle the return for these commands.

So you can fire off multiple queries with the sqlcommand.BeginExecuteReader, for example, and then you have a some options of how to handle/know when it's finished when you issue the sqlcommand.EndExecuteReader. Brief overview of options with some descriptions:

1. Asynchronous Polling - basically sending the sql command(s) and then repeatedly checking the IsCompleted property of the SqlAsyncResult until it returns.
2. Asynchronous Callback - you provide a callback routine as a parameter along with the sql command with this method, e.g. onSqlQueryComplete ( sort of like regular event handling), and that gets called when it finishes.
3. Asynchronous Wait - this one is used if you want to wait and monitor your sql calls process/progress.

Each of the asynchronous options has pros/cons depending on what exactly you want to achieve. Using the number 2 callback option above, pseduo-code would look something like:

```
command = (Build all sql command stuff)
AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(HandleSqlCallback);
command.BeginExecuteReader(callback, command);

command.BeginExecuteReader()

method HandleSqlCallback(IAsyncResult result) {
do stuff when sql done
command.EndExecuteReader(result)
}
```

Microsoft has much better and more complete examples than this, but this gives you a general idea of the format. 
MSDN link for [SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szdt0kc.aspx#Y1000)